# "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"

Tags: vb.net, exception

I am running a VB.NET program and having an error of

"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"

My code looks like below.

```
  If Status.InvokeRequired Then
        Try
            Status.Invoke(New delegateoneArg(AddressOf onChangeEvent), ws)
            Catch ex As DivideByZeroException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        End Try
    Else
        onChangeEvent(ws)
    End If
```

I have the error in line...
Status.Invoke(New delegateoneArg(AddressOf onChangeEvent), ws)

Comment: Please, show the code of `onChangeEvent`. Your error is probably there.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Invoke` method of the status object.  This is accessing an index with an out of range value.

Answer (score 0):

Check the definition of `onChangeEvent` handler. You may have accessed indexes there.
Post more details for a robust answer.